# Trying to parse a file, check its size, then send report.. this fails. :(

Tags: bash

Noob question i'm sure.. But Noob needs help!

I have a script that downloads a ham radio file, does some stuff with it, then sends me an email with its final work. The problem is, Sometime's it comes up short. I'm not sure where it is dropping some data, and quite frankly i'm not sure I care (though I probably should..). My solution was to run the script, check the output of the file, and if it's over 96k, email it. If not.. re-run the script.
It fails on the 'until' process even if the file is above the correct size.

While i'm sure it can be done in other languages, Bash is what i'm currently familiar enough with to try and make this work better. So a bash solution is what i'm looking for. I am also alright with any streamlining that could be done, though it's not intensive by any means to run this currently!

Here's what I have..

```
dt=`date '+%D %T.%6N'`
#
wget -O ~/file1 "https://www.radioid.net/static/users.csv"

egrep 'Washington,United States|Oregon,United States|Idaho,United States|Montana,United States|British Columbia' ~/file1 > ~/PNW1

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {sub(/ .*/, "", $3)} {gsub("Washington", "WA",$5}{gsub("Idaho", "ID",$5)} {gsub("Montana", "MT",$5)} {gsub("Oregon", "OR",$5)} {gsub("Brit$

sed "s/'/ /g" ~/PNW_Contact.txt > ~/PNW_Contacts.txt

rm ~/PNW_Contact.txt
rm ~/file1
rm ~/PNW1

sudo cp ~/PNW_Contacts.txt /var/www/html/PNW_Contacts.txt

until [[ $(find /home/kc7aad/PNW_Contacts.txt -type f -size +96000c 2>/dev/null) ]]; do

echo "$dt" - Failed >> ~/ids.log
sleep 10
done

echo "$dt" - Success >> ~/ids.log

mail -s "PNW DMR Contacts Update" kc7aad@gmail.com -A ~/PNW_Contacts.txt < /home/kc7aad/PNW_Message.txt
```

If I run this script manually, it does succeed. If I let Cron try to complete this, it fails.

I think that's all the detail that is needed. Please let m eknow if there are any questions!

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/808555/why-is-this-cronjob-not-working Try using full paths, or maybe $HOME, instead of tilde.